# installing git version of gnu screen on a rh6 linux with no root permissions

Tags: installation, centos, gnu-screen

How I would go about installing git version of gnu screen on a centos with no root permissions?

I tried this:

```
mkdir ~/work
cd ~/work
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/screen.git
cd screen/src

./autogen.sh


autoheader: WARNING: Using auxiliary files such as `acconfig.h', `config.h.bot'
autoheader: WARNING: and `config.h.top', to define templates for `config.h.in'
autoheader: WARNING: is deprecated and discouraged.
autoheader: 
autoheader: WARNING: Using the third argument of `AC_DEFINE' and
autoheader: WARNING: `AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED' allows to define a template without
autoheader: WARNING: `acconfig.h':
autoheader: 
autoheader: WARNING:   AC_DEFINE([NEED_FUNC_MAIN], 1,
autoheader:             [Define if a function `main' is needed.])
autoheader: 
autoheader: WARNING: More sophisticated templates can also be produced, see the
autoheader: WARNING: documentation.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compile git version requires newer version of GNU Autoconf(and probably needs newer version of GNU m4).

- http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/
- http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/

In my example at Scientific Linux 6.1.

```
cd ~/work
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/m4/m4-1.4.16.tar.bz2
tar xjf m4-1.4.16.tar.bz2
cd m4-1.4.16 && ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local && make && make install

cd ~/work
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-2.68.tar.bz2
tar xjf autoconf-2.68.tar.bz2
cd autoconf-2.68 && ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local && make && make install
```

and now compile gnu screen.

```
cd ~/work/screen/src
./autogen.sh

./configure --prefix=$HOME/local \
            --enable-pam \
            --enable-colors256 \
            --enable-rxvt_osc \
            --enable-use-locale \
            --enable-telnet
make && make install
```

Hope this helps.